# Adding in ID with session?

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I have got my login and sessions working, however I would like to be able to also call the ID of the username too but I am not sure on how to do this. Any help would be great!

So, I am trying to add in `$_SESSION['id'] = $id;`  but am not sure what to add.

```
<?php
require_once 'config.php';

$username = $password = "";
$username_err = $password_err = "";


if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){



if(empty(trim($_POST["username"]))){
    $username_err = 'Please enter username.';
} else{
    $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
}


    $password_err = 'Please enter your password.';
} else{
if(empty(trim($_POST['password']))){
    $password = trim($_POST['password']);
}


if(empty($username_err) && empty($password_err)){

    $sql = "SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username = ?";

    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){

        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);


        $param_username = $username;


        if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){

            mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);


            if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1){                    

                mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $username, $hashed_password);
                if(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){
                    if(password_verify($password, $hashed_password)){

                        session_start();
                        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;      
                        header("location:app.php");
                    } else{

                        $password_err = 'The password you entered was not valid.';
                    }
                }
            } else{

                $username_err = 'No account found with that username.';
            }
        } else{
            echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
        }
    }


    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}


mysqli_close($link);
}
?>
```

Comment: You have a reasonably small program. You can debug this one yourself, using [these excellent suggestions](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). *(warning: these are simple steps, but it still might not be easy going)*

Comment: Thank you, I did have a go at it but was changing the wrong areas (bind_param instead of bind_result). I will take a read and get better :)

Comment: That is good to hear! You will be welcomed on this site. (And sometimes I'm a bit too quick to say, "Buh! This one is easy! Go take another look on your own" ... when maybe it's not so easy after all.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the ID to the query, assuming you have an ID column.  You need this to get the ID from the database.

```
$sql = "SELECT username, password, id FROM users WHERE username = ?";
```

Change the bind result.  The BIND result is where the variables get assigned.

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $username, $hashed_password, $id);
```

Then get the ID in the password verify section:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;   
$_SESSION['id'] = $id; 
header("location:app.php");
```